# What is the difference between state equation, characteristic equation and input equation of a JK flip flop?

Tags: digital

I know input equations are the equations that algebraically represent the combinational circuit input of the JK flip flop. I also know characteristic equation represents next state as a function of inputs and present state. But What is a state equation? What is the difference between these three? State equation and characteristic equation seems to have identical definitions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this doesn't appear to be a programming question.

Comment: Where should I be asking then?

Answer (score 0):

From what I have gathered after going through a textbook by Morris-Mano, you could make a sequential circuit using any type of flip-flop. Each flip-flop has its own **characteristic equations** that describe how the inputs and the present state dictate the next state.

In any sequential circuit, knowing the next state of a flip-flop is of essence. The inputs to the flip-flop might be the output some combinational circuit. The equations that describe the inputs are called **input equations**.

Knowing both the characteristic equations and input equations will enable you to predict the next state of the various flip-flops in your circuit. The characteristic and input equations can be condensed into **state equations**. These **state equations** will relate the inputs to the *sequential circuit* with the outputs of the flip-flop.

**Note the distinction between characteristic and state equations. A characteristic equation relates the inputs to the *flip-flop* (and not to the sequential circuit) with the output of the flip-flop.**